# How to stop a UIView that is moving?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to stop a UIView that is moving?
Or a view that is decelerating.

The problem is, for example:

I have a method changing the position of the View upon a click event of a button; at same time another dragging event can change the position of the View. If I let the dragging event occur first, then while the View is decelerating, quickly I click B, the View's position would change according to the method behind B, but it will instantly go back to where it was decelerating and continue to decelerating. The View wont go back to where button B indicates even it finishes decelerating.

The code is as below.

First I use KVO to make the View (i.e. _topView is the code) responds to the contentOffset of a tableView (upon the tableView is dragged, the View would move).

```
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context

{
   CGPoint contentOffset = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGPointValue];

   CGRect topFrame = _topView.frame;

   topFrame.origin.y = -(contentOffset.y + TOP_SECTION_HEIGHT);
   _topView.frame = topFrame;
}
```

Then upon the buttonB is clicked, the animation below would be triggered.

```
    topFrame = CGRectMakke(...);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        _topView.frame = topFrame;//topView
        targetTableView.contentOffset = targetViewTargetOffset;
    }];
```

Comment: Show your `UIView` "moving" code.

Comment: KVO is not a good way to animate views. Why would you not just animate everything together in the animation block?

Comment: @JanGreve cause I have to make the View move along with the tableView, even the latter is decelerating

Comment: @WhiteWhite if you are animating something along side a scroll view then you don't need to animate it at all. Just respond to the scrollViewDidScroll method and update the frame directly. It will look like it's animating because the scroll view is animating.

Comment: @Fogmeister  My case is a little bit more complicated. Actually the tableView being observed is from another controller, so I cant use scrollView delegate method directly(the tableView's delegate is it's own controller). Another fact is, there are 2 more tableViews needed to be observed, thus KVO is actually more convenient in this case. But you are right, KVO is not perfect here, cause it's code is executed no mater the tableView is moving or decelerating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand the problem, you should stop the tableview decelerating and then call the method for button event.
to stop decelerating when the button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //this will stop table view animations
    [targetTableView setContentOffset:targetTableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
    //then you can adjust the frame of a view accurately
    topFrame = CGRectMakke(...);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        _topView.frame = topFrame;//topView
        targetTableView.contentOffset = targetViewTargetOffset;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Btw another way is to give up KVO, as it's code is executed no mater the tableView is moving or decelerating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will helpfull for you.:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
// other animation properties

// set view properties

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your view is moving?

The point is, if it's just an aesthetic animation, you can create a copy of your view with `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`, hide your original view and move this snapshot on top of all, and then delete the snapshot and move your original view to the end position of the animation. It's a bit memory/battery expensive, but your animation is completely independent of your KVO code.

If it's a more important component, with stronger interactions, you should add a flag (ex: `isAnimated`) to your KVO to prevent the change of position when your animation is launched.

As @Fogmeister said, KVO is not the best for animation, even more with scroll views since they have a delegate for that (`scrollviewDidScroll`).